# C++ 11 move semantics vs C++ 98

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics

I've studied c++ 11 move semantics and I have such a question.

For example:

if we have a

```
vector<T> vt; // also assume that T have pointers on data in separate memory
vt.push_back(...);
```

assume `vt` lacks unused capacity. Then in c++98 it will allocated more memory and copy (calls constructor copy) for every T object with data that they points on.

For example:

t1 -> t1 data => will be copied t_cop1 -> (t1_cop1 data)
t2 -> t2 data => t_cop2 -> (t2_cop2 data)

C++ 11 move semantics allow to move all T objects (just copy a pointers, but do not copy data in separate memory by calling move constructors).

So the question is why cannot we do the same in C++98, why cannot we implement push_back just to copy the memory(which contains the pointers t1, t2 so t_cop1 and t2_cop2 will be created with the same pointers) and after that free it (t1 and t2 using `free(void*)` for example)?

UPD: Ok, I will try to explain my question on more simple example:

For instance if we have a class A that contains a pointer to some datastructure Data.
We implement a copy constructor that copies the pointer "data"

```
class A {
public:
    A() {};
    A(const A& a) {
        data = a.data;
    }
private:
    struct Data{};
    Data* data;
};

// And I want to implement "move semantics" by calling the copy constructor (that copies just pointer)

A* a = new A();
A* b(a);

// and then somehow free "a" object (but not call the destructor)
free(a); // or a = NULL
```

As I understand that's what move semantics almost do (but leave a in some consistent state). So as I think we actually had an ability to implement move in old C++. Is't it?

Also we can do the same in previous example with vector

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding move semantics ...

Comment: There is not difference between C++11 and C++98 here because when moving pointers the pointers are just copied. Also a `vector<T>` where `T` is a pointer will only move around the pointers and never what the pointer points to.

Comment: Exectly, but C++ 98 will call a deep copy so it will copy not just pointers but all data that pointers points to. So the question is why cannot we implement move semantics by C++98

Comment: @Nikita no, c++98 will not automatically do a deep copy. It will simply copy the pointer value, just like c++11.

Comment: I can't figure out the notation in that "t1 -> t1 data ..." line.

Comment: @bames53 Ok. So Am i right that in C++98 we can implement move by copying (not deep) the pointers (from old vector) and then call free(void*) for old memory which we just copied?

Comment: @Nikita no, freeing the old pointer invalidates the copy.

Comment: Move semantics does not just do a shallow copy (your type `A` has a copy ctor that does perform a shallow copy). Its intention is *transfer of acquired resourced*. Transfer implies changing the source: it no longer owns the tranfered resource. You can't do that with a copy constructor that takes a reference to **constant** `A`. `std::auto_ptr` tried to transfer resources with a copy ctor like `auto_ptr(auto_ptr&)` (non-const), but this causes too many problems.

Comment: You may want to read some of the proposals for move semantics. Typically, library features are preferred to language features, so you have to explain/argue why this can't be solved by a mere library feature. For example, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm

Comment: @dyp yes, auto_ptr is really what I was looking for. What kind of problems will using auto_ptr cause?

Comment: @Nikita Uhh.. I didn't really ever *use* `auto_ptr`; all I know is that it leads to very subtle code. For example, it infects classes which own an `auto_ptr` with its weird copy semantics. You then need to know the types involved if you want to understand what `T x; T y = x;` does. Does it transfer resources from `x` to `y`? Does it perform a deep copy? You will also need to write explicitly the copy functions for such classes, since they might have other data members which perform deep copies, to get a consistent behaviour.

Comment: Those odd semantics are why C++11 prefers `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. This `auto_ptr` trick (and custom "smart pointer" classes similar to it) is what I was referring to below regarding "getting `operator new` and `operator delete` involved."

Comment: This: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html#20.4.5%20-%20Class%20template%20auto_ptr explains why `auto_ptr` did not work.

Answer (score 3):

"Move semantics" provides a way for the compiler to pass references to things like constructors that can be differentiated as *lvalue references* (the kind you're used to, found in C++98) and *rvalue references* (new with C++11, using the `&&` notation, these refer to objects that are temporary and intermediate, and likely not to last past the current statement).

So now we can write a copy constructor ("make the new object a copy of this one") and a different move constructor ("make the new object a copy of this one, and oh by the way the source object is a temporary that will be destroyed next, so if you want to optimize in a way that doesn't leave the source object intact, go ahead").

So for example, in a container class, you can copy the container class with the copy constructor, and the new copy will contain a full duplicate of all its contents (which means things like element-by-element copy construction of the contents will happen). But the move constructor can skip all that work and simply swap internals with the source container, simply taking over the contents of the source container and leaving the source container empty. (Later the source container gets destroyed, which should be trivial since it's empty.) This can usually be done in constant time instead of O(N) or worse.

You can't do the equivalent *as a constructor* (and thus with a temporary object) in C++98 because it only knows how to make a copy. There is a way to achieve a similar effect via the `swap()` function (and method in some classes), but that had to be written explicitly. (Basically, to move the contents of container `a` into newly-constructed empty container `b`, you would call `swap(a, b);`, then destroy `a` which would then be empty.)

---

One example of a case where you just can't do the right thing in C++98 is initializing a vector with the result of a function that returns a vector:

```
vector<int> fibonacci(int n) { 
    vector<int> result;
    if(n <= 0) return result;
    result.push_back(0);
    if(n <= 1) return result;
    result.push_back(1);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        result.push_back(result[i] + result[i - 1]);
    return result; 
}

vector<int> datavect = fibonacci(10);
```

C++98 and C++11 will both elide away the function return copy (creating `result` in the spot where the return value is stored) but C++98 can only call the copy constructor for `datavect` because there are no move semantics. C++11 can call the move constructor instead, which can move the storage from the temporary return value into `datavect`. There's not really a way to do this in C++98 without getting `operator new` and `operator delete` involved and returning pointers instead of objects, beating on the (non-deterministic time) free store for no gain.

Comment: Yes, that is what move semantics do. So my question is how (or why not) we cannot implement move semantics in C++ 98?

Comment: See my last paragraph. In short: you have to do it manually, and can't do it at all in some cases like functions returning containers (as opposed to pointers or references).

Comment: Yes, I agree that in the cases of swap and fibonacci old c++ is not suitable. But in my example (and with vector also) the performance can be improved by emulating move semantics. So why they didn't implement it in stl before C++11?

Comment: @Nikita The problem is not STL, but the user-defined types. You would require having this strange behaviour (copy == resource transfer) for all value types of containers which want this optimization. Essentially like `std::auto_ptr`. This however breaks the usual copy semantics, where copying (per convention) means *deep copy*. So you can use such a type as a value type in a container, but then you can't really use the same type outside the container. You could change the STL and introduce a new ctor like `A(A&, transfer_resource_t)`, but this won't work naturally with rvalues.